# Why i can not use using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations in my class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in `asp.net mvc` and first time create new web application and in my project solution right click and add new project to solution and add class library to my project,and name it `Datalayer`,so in `Datalayer`create new class and name it `PageGroup`,in `PageGroup` want to add `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to name space but get this error:

> A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods...

I add entity frame work to `datalayer` but so not work!,how can i solve that problem?

this is my class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Datalayer
{
    public class PageGroup
    {
        [Key]
        public int GroupID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in `[Key]` get error.

Comment: Show your code. You obviously have some declarations that are not inside a class

Comment: @StephenMuecke my friend why you vote down me! i say's a new in asp.net mvc

Comment: @StephenMuecke please wait to update my question

Comment: @StephenMuecke i update my question,please review that.thanks

Comment: The code you have shown will not cause that error (check that you have included the correct error message). And you have not included `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` in your code

Comment: @StephenMuecke when not include using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; give me missing assembly error on [key],and when i use using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; give me DataAnnotations not exists in name space ComponentModel error.

Comment: But that is not the error you have shown in your question! Edit your question to explain what is really happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add assembly reference in your application.
Go to Reference->Add Reference-> Select System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations assembly to your application.

Then use the namespace in your application

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Please find screenshot for reference
[image]

Comment: but when i right click on the class library and add reference i can't see any assembly

Comment: Please find the screenshot which I have added

Answer (score 0):

Add assembly `system.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation` in your current project.

Go to Add reference> Assemblies > Framework  and choose `system.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation`

If this is not present in your current assembly then download it form nuget package manager.

Write click on your project.> manage nuget packages and search for System.componentmodel and select appropriate package and install.